# passing dates in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have the following issue with python with script in linux:
I am executing my_query.py passing as a parameter the date 2017-03-01

```
python my_query.py 2017-03-01
```

How can I create a loop to iterate over that date so it cover the entire month (from date 1 to end of month).

Thanks!

Comment: [python datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Which part are you specifically having trouble with? Getting the command line arg? Converting it to a datetime object? Creating an iterator? Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import timedelta


def dates_between(start, end):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += timedelta(days=1)


start = parse('2017-03-01').date()

for day in dates_between(start, start + relativedelta(months=1)):
    print(day)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `monthrange` from `calendar`

```
import sys
from calendar import monthrane

datestr = sys.argv[1]

year, month, day = datestr.split('-')

for day in xrange(1, monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1] + 1):

    print day
```